# How to update rows / set row data in server side row model type in ag grid?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

My data model looks like this. Array of objects containing title and created_date.

```
{ 
    title : String
    created_date: Date
}
```

I have defined a column definition which only renders the title. However, I'd like to sort the rows based on the created_date, without creating a created_date column. There will be an external button detached from the table, which will call the api to get the data. I am using row model type `serverSide`. I have the sorted data from the backend. I just need to update the data / refresh the data. How can I achieve this ? I have so far tried `setRowData(updatedRows)`. but its giving me an error saying `cannot call setRowData unless using normal row model`. Is there any way to update my rows in this `serverSide` row model type settings ?

Comment: setRowData is only for client side row model. Have you looked into this example - https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-server-side-model-sorting/#example-sorting

Answer (score 0):

Calling `this.gridApi.setServerSideDatasource(myDataSource);` and passing in your dataSource will do the trick. Check [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/server-side-model-datasource/) for details